# Dynamically add into array and retrieve sum

Tags: php

```
foreach ($_POST['ECL'] as $lt) {

    //SQL select statements are run.  Each $lt is a where condition where results are obtained from the DB.
}
```

I want to take a count of each result and sum this up.  The total would be records obtained. I can get the record count for each individual $lt, but I am unable to sum them.  All help would be appreciated.

**[update] the number of $lt is not fixed.** $lt can be 1,2,3,4...  Counter such as $i++ does no work

Comment: I think you need to include some more code - even an example of the values of the variables you show - and an expected output of your example would be good

Comment: what database are you using ? mysql ? mssql ? PDO ?

Comment: This looks more like an SQL question than a PHP question

Comment: @Pete thats exactly how i read and answered it ...

Comment: @ManseUK - yep, your answer appeared after my comment. If we had some code and/or examples we might be able to condense this into a single query.

Comment: @Pete nope .. my answer was 1 minute before your comment :-) ... but yes totally agree - the question wasnt worded well at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) or [mssql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-num-rows.php) - they return the number of rows in a result

```
$count = 0;  // setup count variable
foreach ($_POST['ECL'] as $lt) {

    //SQL select statements are run.  Each $lt is a where condition where results are obtained from the DB.
    $count += mysql_num_rows($result);  // add results count to our counter
}
echo $count; // this will be the total number of rows the queries returned
```

Comment: @Jean dont sound so surprised :-) ... its not exactly complex adding a couple of numbers together ....

Comment: I actually did not think it the way you pointed out.  The statements in my code before and after are a little complex.  :)

Comment: I have to give @manseUK the correct for pointing out correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Set a counter before the loop, increment it during the loop, retrieve the sum at the end. Simple...

Comment: It does not work by putting a counter.  Assuming I place a $i++, each time the $lt is new, the counter refreshes.  $lt is never fixed. It can be 1,2,3,4..

Comment: You're supposed to put `$cnt=0` before the loop, `$cnt += number of rows` inside it (replacing with the code you say you know how to do), and then after the loop `$cnt` will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question says that you're adding the result rows from each $lt into an array (I don't see that in the posted code though).

If that's the case, and you're inserting one array record per row, the length of the array should serve as your count.